# How to split this String in two parts?

Tags: ms-access, vba

I would like to split a string like this in Access 2000 (Visual Basic function):

```
"[Results]

 [Comments]"
```

in two parts:

- the results part
- the comments part

As you can notice, these two parts are separated by an empty line (always, this is our separator).

[Results] and [Comments] are blocks of text. We don't care what's in it except:

the results part doesn't have any empty lines in it, so the first empty line we see is the separator one.

I want my function to extract the Comments part only.

Here is what i tried:

```
Public Function ExtractComm(txt As String) As String

Dim emptyLine As Integer

txt = Trim(txt)

'emptyLine = first empty line index ??
emptyLine = InStrRev(txt, (Chr(13) + Chr(10)) & (Chr(13) + Chr(10)))

'Comments part = all that is after the empty line ??
ExtractComm = Mid(txt, emptyLine + 4)

End Function
```

But it doesn't work well.
If I do:

```
ExtractComm(
   "Res1
    Res2

    Comment1

    Comment2"
)
```

I want to obtain:

```
"Comment1

Comment2"
```

but I only obtain Comment2. Any idea to extract the comment part ?

Thanks a lot !

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Maybe you need to use `InStr` instead of `InStrRev`

**InStrRev**

Returns the position of the first occurrence of one string within another, starting from the right side of the string.

**InStr**
Returns an integer specifying the start position of the first occurrence of one string within another.